# Find the position from a string in a substring in a sentence

Tags: python, regex

I have the sentence : `Take 1 tablet in the morning and at noon for **1** week`

I try to find the position of the **1** element corresponding to the **1** for `1 week`

But if i use re.search for the '1' element in my sentence i've got the **1** position from the **1** element corresponding to `1 tablet`

Thanks to NLP I can extract the element `for 1 week`. So i would like to find the **1** element in the substring `for 1 week` in the sentence.

Comment: Search for the whole string `1 week`, not just `1`.

Comment: You should state the string exactly. If the asterisks are not part of the string they should not be present. If you wish to draw attention to part of the string do it in words after showing the string. Only after reading though your question did I realise your sentence evidently was not intended to contain asterisks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the span of `for 1 week` and the span of `1` within `for 1 week` (this is quite trivial in this example but would be more interesting with a more complex regex):

```
s = 'Take 1 tablet in the morning and at noon for 1 week'

import re
m = re.search('for 1 week', s)
start, stop = m.span()
m2 = re.search('1', m.group())
start2, stop2 = m2.span()
start+start2
```

output:

```
>>> start+start2
45

>>> s[45]
'1'
```

slightly more complex example:

```
m = re.search('(for|during) \d+ (week|day|month)', s)
start, stop = m.span()
m2 = re.search('\d+', m.group())
start2, stop2 = m2.span()
print(f'position {start+start2}: {s[start+start2]}')
```

output: `position 45: 1`